# Can the Android Gradle aapt tool ignore folders?

Tags: gradle, build, assets, aapt

```
android {
    aaptOptions {
        //unicorn_emoji is folder, in assets/unicorn_emoji

        ignoreAssetsPattern "!/unicorn_emoji"//does not work

        ignoreAssetsPattern "**/unicorn_emoji"//does not work

        ignoreAssetsPattern "/unicorn_emoji"//does not work

        ignoreAssetsPattern "**/unicorn_emoji"//does not work

        ignoreAssetsPattern "!unicorn_emoji"//does not work

        ignoreAssetsPattern "unicorn_emoji"//does not work
    }
}
```

I've tried many ways but can't get it to work. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
android {
    aaptOptions {
        //unicorn_emoji is folder, in assets/unicorn_emoji

        ignoreAssetsPattern "unicorn_emoji*"
    }
}
```

Comment: I've found a better way to delete every file I want